# Implementing voting logic based on previous score

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering how to handle this. I've done it previously, but it involves a lot of if/else statements and I can't seem to figure it out without resorting to that. I posted it on codereview and got someone to help me re-facor it, but now I'm trying to get this functionality working properly.

How this works now is, if you click "up", it'll increase the score 1 point. If you click "up" again, it'll decrease the score. That's fine. If you click "down" it'll have the same behavior. It will not however go below 0 ever, since I don't want to display a negative score.

Right now I'm just checking to see if the previous or next buttons have `.upColor` and `.downColor` css classes on them, which check if they've already voted. I'm having trouble trying to update the proper score based off of this especially if the original score is 0, or if the score is 10.

Logic I'm trying to implement:

E.g. Original score is 0:

- User votes up. Score goes to 1. User votes down. Score goes to 0 (not -1)
- User votes down. Score stays at 0. User votes up. Score goes to 1.

E.g. Original score is 10:

- User votes up. Score goes to 11. User votes down. Score goes to 9.
- User votes down. Score goes to 9. User votes up. Score goes to 11.

Code:

```
$(function() {

var handleClick = function($btn) {
    var $voteContainer = $btn.parent();
    var scoreNode = $('.count');
    var originalScore = Number($voteContainer.data('original-score'));

    if ($btn.hasClass('down')) {
        if ($btn.prevAll('.up').hasClass('upColor')) {
            $btn.prevAll('.up').toggleClass('upColor');
            alert('voted up now voting down, decrease 2 points, but don\'t go below 0.');
        }
    }


    if ($btn.hasClass('up')) {
        if ($btn.nextAll('.down').hasClass('downColor')) {
            $btn.nextAll('.down').toggleClass('downColor');
            alert('voted down now voting up, increase by 2 points');
        }
    }

    var increment = $btn.hasClass('up') ? 1 : $btn.hasClass('down') && originalScore > 0 ? -1 : 0; // default

    // Only do something if there is an increment
    if (increment) {
        var currentScore = Number(scoreNode.text()) || 0;
        var newScore = currentScore + increment;
        var diff = Math.abs(originalScore - newScore);

        // Can't go more than + or - 1
        if (diff > 1) {
            newScore = originalScore;
        }

        // Set new displayed value
        scoreNode.text(newScore);
    }
    $btn.hasClass('up') ? $btn.toggleClass('upColor') : $btn.toggleClass('downColor');
};

var upBtn = $('.up');
var downBtn = $('.down');

upBtn.add(downBtn).click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);

    handleClick($btn);
});

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3kCPw/

Comment: I can't seem to find your exact problem, can you please tell us what you exactly want? It seems to work for me from what I gathered your goal is

Comment: Sure. First I click `up`, and it'll add add 1 (http://imgur.com/8FmnY.png). Then I click `down` and it'll decrease only 1 (http://imgur.com/IPgfj.png) but it should decrease 2. Then if I click `down` again, it'll go to 1, but it should go back to the original score (http://i.imgur.com/eZ0ub.png)

Comment: your logic prevents a change of more than one and resets to original. You never modify the stored original either.

Comment: I added an answer that should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I won't rewrite your code because it will take me too long, but I will give you some code that I would have used from the start.

Start with the original number:

```
var original_vote = 2;
var current_vote = original_vote;
```

Keep this as a constant to refer to for the future. Then when you click the up vote, you can add 1 to that simply with:

```
current_vote = original_vote + 1;
```

Then un-checking the up vote would make it:

```
current_vote = original_vote;
```

Then just do the opposite for down voting.

Keeping the original number ensures that you will not accidentally make the votes go out of the scope that it should.

Hope this helps!